# Java control if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm using the below free text to learn intro to java and I am having trouble understanding the difference between the code segments:

http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/downloads/javanotes7-linked.pdf

**Example 1**

```
    int x;
    x = -1;
    if (x < 0)
        x = 1;
    else
        x = 2;
```

**Example 2**

```
    int x;
    x = -1;
    if (x < 0)
        x = 1;
    if (x >= 0)
        x = 2;
```

In **Example 1**, x is 1; In **Example 2**, x is 2.

On the right, if -1 is not > or = to 0 then shouldn't the output be 1? Could someone please explain why the output would instead be 2?

Comment: on the left; program executes else block only if condition is false. so no need to explain right one its just executing lines in order.

Comment: This is a very basic question, please close it.

Comment: @ShivaShinde: What on earth is wrong with basic questions?  Everyone starts with the basics.

Comment: Can someone send a mail to the author of that... thing. Is on the second page.

Comment: where ever you got that code, ***stop using that site as a reference that is craptastic code if I ever saw any***, it should say `if/else if/else` multiple `if` statements one after another like that just creates an impossible to reason about statemachine nightmare. cyclomatic complexity goes through the roof! **NEVER write code like this!** Also **NEVER leave off the `{ }` it will cause you nothing but pain when you can't figure out why the subsequent lines of code run all the time.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson or maybe DO use it. Because that code is there _to explain why the code is bad_. "The author is literally using it to address misconception or misunderstanding of new programmers about how `if` statements operate by saying that the two are not equivalent even if they can look the same to a new programmer. The author's point being (coincidentally) illustrated by OP being confused at what the difference would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the second if statement is evaluated, `x` the first has already taken effect--so the value of `x` is now 1.

```
if (x < 0)
   x = 1;


if (x >= 0) //x is 1 because you've already evaluated the above!
   x = 2;
```

The `else` keyword creates *mutually exclusive* branches: only one can be executed.  So if you had this, the behavior would be as you expected:

```
if (x < 0)
   x = 1;
else if (x >= 0)
   x = 2;
```

Comment: This answer is correct, @TheJuniorProgrammer... the second example contains two if statements.

Answer (score 2):

In the Example 1, only one of the statements `x = 1;` or `x = 2;` will be executed because it uses an `if...else` statement.

In the Example 2, both statements will be executed because it uses two separate `if` statements, and because both conditions are true at the time they are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example; first you go through the first `if` condition:

```
x = -1;

if (x < 0) x = 1;
```

x is less than 0, so x becomes 1.

When you go to the second `if` condition:

```
if (x >= 0) x = 2;
```

x is **still** 1, and 1 is greater than 0, so x becomes 2.